# plot_ly slider error with ploly R version ‘4.5.6’

Tags: r, slider, plotly

tried to run code below (got from this link: https://plot.ly/r/sliders/)

when I check my version with: packageVersion('plotly')
I am running:
[1] ‘4.5.6’

The example is in :
[1] ‘4.5.6.900’

When I try to run that exact lines of code I get and error:

### \ #ERROR

```
Warning message:
'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'sliders'
Valid attributes include:
'font', 'title', 'titlefont', 'autosize', 'width', 'height', 'margin', 'paper_bgcolor', 'plot_bgcolor', 'separators', 'hidesources', 'smith', 'showlegend', 'dragmode', 'hovermode', 'xaxis', 'yaxis', 'scene', 'geo', 'legend', 'annotations', 'shapes', 'images', 'updatemenus', 'ternary', 'mapbox', 'radialaxis', 'angularaxis', 'direction', 'orientation', 'barmode', 'bargap', 'mapType'
```

I need some help here, what do I need to do? Do i need to get ‘4.5.6.900’? ...and if so where can I get it? ...or is there something else I need to do?

### # CODE

```
library(plotly)
packageVersion('plotly')

x <- seq(0,10, length.out = 1000)

# create data
aval <- list()
for(step in 1:11){
  aval[[step]] <-list(visible = FALSE,
                      name = paste0('v = ', step),
                      x=x,
                      y=sin(step*x))
}
aval[3][[1]]$visible = TRUE

# create steps and plot all traces
steps <- list()
p <- plot_ly()
for (i in 1:11) {
  p <- add_lines(p,x=aval[i][[1]]$x,  y=aval[i][[1]]$y, visible = aval[i][[1]]$visible, 
                 name = aval[i][[1]]$name, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', hoverinfo = 'name', 
                 line=list(color='00CED1'), showlegend = FALSE)

  step <- list(args = list('visible', rep(FALSE, length(aval))),
               method = 'restyle')
  step$args[[2]][i] = TRUE  
  steps[[i]] = step 
}  

# add slider control to plot
p <- p %>%
  layout(sliders = list(list(active = 0,
                             currentvalue = list(prefix = "Frequency: "),
                             steps = steps)))
p
```

Comment: maybe this: devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")

Answer (score 2):

Currently CRAN release is version 4.5.6 but sliders are in the development version 4.5.6.900. As mentioned by MLavoie, you can use `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")` to install the development version. Also, you can read more here https://plot.ly/r/getting-started/

Comment: So I downloaded the zipfile and used the command:

`install.packages("C:/.../Downloads/plotly-master.zip", repos = NULL, type="source")`

from:
[link](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly)

then noticed that there was a plotly-master folder in the R library

then tried this code:
`library(plotly-master)`

and got error:
Error in library(plotly - master) : 'package' must be of length 1

.........then tried looking at plotly library:
`library(plotly)`
`packageVersion("plotly")`

and got version:
[1] ‘4.5.6’

Comment: you can just run `if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")` then `library(plotly)`